# Extremely slow WordPress user import on XAMPP

Tags: performance, wordpress, xampp

I'm posting this question here because I'm not sure it's a WordPress issue.

I'm running XAMPP on my local system, with 512MB max headroom and a 2.5-hour php timeout. I'm importing about 11,000 records into the WordPress wp_user and wp_usermeta tables via a custom script. The only unknown quantity (performance-wise) on the WordPress end is the `wp_insert_user` and `update_user_meta` calls. Otherwise it's a straight CSV import.

The process to import 11,000 users and create 180,000 usermeta entries took over 2 hours to complete. It was importing about 120 records a minute. That seems awfully slow.

Are there known performance issues importing user data into WordPress? A quick Google search was unproductive (for me).

Are there settings I should be tweaking beyond the timeout in XAMPP? Is its mySQL implementation notoriously slow?

I've read something about virus software dramatically slowing down XAMPP. Is this a myth?

Comment: What custom script are you using? It *shouldn't* be slow, but it depends on what you define as slow, how the script is written, and your local environment. Don't really know without seeing the script and/or data.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's pretty vague. The script is quite lean, but does use a third party lib for the actual CSV translation (as opposed to the built-in). But to give you an idea, 11,000 records took over 2 hours to import.

Answer (score 2):

yes, there are few issues with local vs. hosted. One of the important things to remember is the max_execution time for php script. You may need to reset the timer once a while during the data upload.

I suppose you have some loop which takes the data row by row from CSV file for example and uses SQL query to insert it into WP database. I usually put this simple snippet into my loop so it will keep the PHP max_exec_time reset:

```
$counter = 1;

// some upload query
if (($handle = fopen("some-file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

mysql_query..... blablabla....


// snippet
if($counter == '20')  // this count 20 loops and resets the counter
{
    set_time_limit(0); 
    $counter = 0;
}       
 $counter = $counter + 1;

} //end of the loop
```

.. also BTW 512MB room is not much if the database is big. Count how much resources is taking your OS and all running apps. I have ove 2Gb WO database and my  MySql needs a lot of RAM to run fast. (depends on the query you are using as well)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know about the `set_time_limit()` trick. Definitely a good one. Thanks also for the memory info. I'll see about bumping up the mySQL limits.